# Interrupt time in DMA operation

Tags: cpu-architecture, numerical, dma

I'm facing difficulty with the following question :

Consider a disk drive with the following specifications .

> 16 surfaces, 512 tracks/surface, 512 sectors/track, 1 KB/sector, rotation speed 3000 rpm. The disk is operated in cycle stealing mode whereby whenever 1 byte word is ready it is sent to memory; similarly for writing, the disk interface reads a 4 byte word from the memory in each DMA cycle. Memory Cycle time is 40 ns. The maximum percentage of time that the CPU gets blocked during DMA operation is?

the solution to this question provided on the only site is :

```
  Revolutions Per Min = 3000 RPM 
     or   3000/60 = 50 RPS 
  In 1 Round it can read = 512 KB 
  No. of tracks read per second = (2^19/2^2)*50
                                = 6553600 ............. (1)
          Interrupt = 6553600 takes 0.2621 sec
          Percentage Gain = (0.2621/1)*100
                          = 26 %
```

I have understood till (1).

Can anybody explain me how has 0.2621 come ? How is the interrupt time calculated? Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing form the numbers you've given, that's 6553600 * 40ns that gives 0.2621 sec.

One quite obvious problem is that the comments in the calculations are somewhat wrong. It's not

```
Revolutions Per Min = 3000 RPM ~ or   3000/60 = 50 RPS 
In 1 Round it can read = 512 KB 
No. of tracks read per second = (2^19/2^2)*50   <- WRONG
```

The numbers are 512K / 4 * 50. So, it's in bytes. How that could be called 'number of tracks'? Reading the full track is 1 full rotation, so the number of tracks readable in 1 second is 50, as there are 50 RPS.

However, the total bytes readable in 1s is then just 512K * 50 since 512K is the amount of data on the track.

But then it is further divided by 4..

So, I guess, the actual comments should be:

```
Revolutions Per Min = 3000 RPM ~ or   3000/60 = 50 RPS 
In 1 Round it can read = 512 KB 
Interrupts per second = (2^19/2^2) * 50 = 6553600 (*)
```

Interrupt triggers one memory op, so then:

```
total wasted: 6553600 * 40ns = 0.2621 sec.
```

However, I don't really like how the 'number of interrupts per second' is calculated. I currently don't see/fell/guess how/why it's just `Bytes/4`.

The only VAGUE explanation of that "divide it by 4" I can think of is:

> At each byte written to the controller's memory, an event is triggered. However the DMA controller can read only PACKETS of 4 bytes. So, the hardware DMA controller must WAIT until there are at least 4 bytes ready to be read. Only then the DMA kicks in and halts the bus (or part of) for a duration of one memory cycle needed to copy the data. As bus is frozen, the processor MAY have to wait. It doesn't NEED to, it can be doing its own ops and work on cache, but if it tries touching the memory, it will need to wait until DMA finishes.

However, I don't like a few things in this "explanation". I cannot guarantee you that it is valid. It really depends on what architecture you are analyzing and how the DMA/CPU/BUS are organized.

Comment: thanks...
i too agree with you that why the total bytes have been divided by 4 but then i took it as if solution is provided by considering only the reading part. but the vague thing is why is it only considering that part because main memory cycle time will be same for reading and writing, i guess?

Comment: and that is 40 ns. one more thing you took controller's memory as the memory mentioned in the question . why?

Comment: ok, forget that last comment I've just deleted. I understood your question finally. By "controller's memory" I meant the vague thing that serves as the DMA's input buffer. It is said that the DMA can transfer only in chunks of 4bytes. So if the drive/whatever emits the data byte-per-byte, then somewhere must be a small 'cache' that accumulates them into 4B packets available for the DMA to transfer. I named it 'controller's memory', because probably it'd be some IO buffer of the drive controller linked by the DMA to some main memory location. But I have no idea where would this buffer be.

Comment: there is one more doubt. can you pls see my updated question and tell m whether my approach is correct or not?

Comment: 1 rotation generates 512 KB. 1 second is 50 rotations. In 1 second, the amount of source data is 512 KB*50 = 25600 KB = 26214400 B. Now, this data is transferred in packets of 4 bytes. This gives you 26214400 B / 4 B = 6553600 transfers to copy all the data. Each tranfer takes 40 ns. 6553600 * 40ns = 0.262144 seconds. So, the whole source data that was generated by the disk during 1.0 second will be copied in 0.262144 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I have an almost similar question to yours, with just one digit changed.
And I think that either there's a typo error in your question or it is intentional.

So, I'll answer your question by assuming the former (first).

Here's the (corrected) question:

> 16 surfaces, 512 tracks/surface, 512 sectors/track, 1 KB/sector, rotation speed 3000 rpm. The disk is operated in cycle stealing mode whereby whenever **one 4 byte word** is ready it is sent to memory; similarly for writing, the disk interface reads a 4 byte word from the memory in each DMA cycle. Memory Cycle time is 40 ns. The maximum percentage of time that the CPU gets blocked during DMA operation is?

Notice: 'one 4 byte word' instead of '1 byte word'.

For the solution, I'll answer from 2 perspectives - a general or basic perspective and other with a little depth (not too much, probably).

```
Common calculation
==================

1 track --> 512 sectors
1 track --> 2^9 sectors

1 sector --> 1 KB
1 sector --> 2^10 B

1 track --> 2^9 * 2^10 B
1 track --> 2^19 B

3000 revolutions per minute (RPM)

3000 revolutions --> 1 minute
3000 revolutions --> 60 seconds
1 revolution --> (60 / 3000) seconds
1 revolution --> (1 / 50) seconds

1 revolution --> 1 track
1 revolution --> 2^19 B
(1 / 50) seconds --> 2^19 B

2^19 B --> (1 / 50) seconds
1 B --> (1 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds
4 B --> 4 * (1 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds
4 B --> (4 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds
4 B --> (2^2 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds
4 B --> (1 / (50 * 2^17)) seconds
4 B --> (1 / (50 * 131072)) seconds
4 B --> (1 / 6553600) seconds

1 second = 10^9 nano-seconds

4 B --> (1 / 6553600) * (1 second)
4 B --> (1 / 6553600) * 10^9 nano-seconds
4 B --> (10^9 / 6553600) nano-seconds
4 B --> 152.5878 nano-seconds
4 B --> 153 nano-seconds

40 nano-seconds --> 1 memory cycle

1 nano-seconds --> (1 / 40) memory cycle

4 B --> 153 * (1 nano-second)
4 B --> 153 * (1 / 40) memory cycle
4 B --> (153 / 40) memory cycle
4 B --> 3.825 memory cycles
4 B --> 4 memory cycles



Common calculation (more mathematical, same as previous section)
================================================================

[Given]
1 track = 512 sectors
1 track = 2^9 sectors

expansion: 2^9 sectors per track.


[Given]
1 sector = 1 KB
1 sector = 2^10 B

expansion: 2^10 Bytes per sector.


[Calculating]
1 track = 2^9 sectors
1 track = 2^9 * (1 sector)
1 track = 2^9 * (2^10 B)
1 track = 2^19 B

expansion: 2^19 Bytes per track
explanation: [ (bytes per track) = (sectors per track) * (bytes per sector) ]


[Given]
3000 revolutions = 1 minute

expansion: 3000 revolutions per minute (RPM)


[Calculating]
3000 revolutions = 1 minute
3000 revolutions = 60 seconds
1 revolution = (60 / 3000) seconds
1 revolution = (1 / 50) seconds

expansion: (1 / 50) seconds per 1 revolution


[Given]
1 revolution = 1 track

expansion: 1 track is fully-covered per revolution


[Calculating]
1 revolution = 1 track
1 revolution = 2^19 B

expansion: 1 revolution covers 2^19 Bytes


[Calculating]
1 revolution = 2^19 B
2^19 B = 1 revolution
2^19 B = (1 / 50) seconds
1 B = (1 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds

expansion: 1 Byte transfer takes (1 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds


[Calculating]
1 B = (1 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds
4 B = 4 * (1 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds
4 B = 2^2 * (1 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds
4 B = (2^2 / (50 * 2^19)) seconds
4 B = (1 / (50 * 2^17)) seconds
4 B = (1 / (50 * 131072)) seconds
4 B = (1 / 6553600) seconds

expansion: 4 Byte transfer takes (1 / 6553600) seconds


[Fact]
1 second = 10^9 nano-seconds


[Calculating]
4 B = (1 / 6553600) seconds
4 B = (1 / 6553600) * (1 second)
4 B = (1 / 6553600) * 10^9 nano-seconds
4 B = (10^9 / 6553600) nano-seconds
4 B = 152.5878 nano-seconds
4 B = 153 nano-seconds

expansion: 4 Byte transfer takes 153 nano-seconds


[Given]
40 nano-seconds = 1 memory cycle

expansion: 1 memory cycle takes 40 nano-seconds


[Calculating]
40 nano-seconds = 1 memory cycle
1 nano-second = (1 / 40) memory cycle

expansion: (1 / 40) memory cycle per nano-second


[Calculating]
4 B = 153 nano-seconds
4 B = 153 * (1 nano-second)
4 B = 153 * (1 / 40) memory cycles
4 B = (153 / 40) memory cycles
4 B = 3.825 memory cycles
4 B = 4 memory cycles

expansion: 4 Byte transfer takes 4 memory cycles


Our common calculation concludes at the statement:
'4 Byte transfer take 4 memory cycles'.



Theoretical and general information
===================================

Firstly, let's see the smallest data transfer unit in computer architecture:

CPU   <---> Cache       : 1 word
Cache <---> main memory : 1 block
CPU   <---> DMA         : 1 word
DMA   <---> main memory : 1 word
DMA   <---> I/O module  : 1 word


Data unit inter-conversions:


1 block = multiple words (not given in question)

 ---------------------------------
| word | word | word | ... | word |   }==> 1 block
 ---------------------------------


1 word = 4 B (given in question)

 -----------------------
| 1 B | 1 B | 1 B | 1 B |   }==> 1 word
 -----------------------



In below section(s), the 'data buffer' refers to the data buffer register
which can store 1 word (4 B as per question), and is either located in
DMA controller or I/O module internally.
(See the end section of this answer for exact definition and (or) more
info regarding this.)



Now, let's see the outline of DMA's working in cycle stealing mode:

Format:: Bus master : who [ --> to whom ] : what

Case 1: Reading from disk and writing to main memory.
CPU : CPU --> DMA    : CPU issues read command to DMA and proceeds
                       with other instructions.
CPU : DMA <-- I/O    : DMA issues read request to I/O module (here, disk)
                       and waits until 1 word is ready for transfer
                       (from data buffer to main memory).
CPU : DMA --> CPU    : DMA blocks CPU's execution for memory-dependent
                       instruction only and begins cycle stealing process
                       by taking bus control.
DMA : DMA --> memory : DMA reads the data from data buffer and writes to
                       main memory.
CPU : DMA --> CPU    : DMA raises an interrupt and notifies CPU that the
                       transfer is completed and returns bus control to CPU.
CPU : CPU            : CPU proceeds with other instructions.

Case 2: Reading from main memory and writing to disk.
CPU : CPU --> DMA    : CPU issues write command to DMA and proceeds with
                       other instructions.
CPU : DMA --> CPU    : DMA blocks CPU's execution for memory-dependent
                       instructions only and begins cycle stealing process
                       by taking bus control.
DMA : DMA <-- memory : DMA reads the data from main memory and writes to
                       data buffer.
CPU : DMA --> CPU    : DMA returns the bus control to CPU.
CPU : CPU            : CPU proceeds with other instructions.
CPU : DMA --> I/O    : DMA issues write request to I/O module (here, disk)
                       and waits until 1 word is written on disk
                       (from data buffer to disk).
CPU : DMA --> CPU    : DMA raises an interrupt and notifies CPU that
                       the transfer is completed.
CPU : CPU            : CPU proceeds with other instructions.

(More details regarding data transfer between main memory and
I/O module (disk) are in upcoming sections of this answer.)

Note: In DMA, the interrupt is raised only at the end in both the cases.


Now, let's look at what 'memory cycle time' means.
By definition, a 'cycle time' means time interval between 2 consecutive
clock pulses, that is, time taken by 1 clock cycle.
And, 1 cycle corresponds to one operation.

So, a 'memory cycle time' means time taken to perform one memory operation,
where an operation is either of type 'read' or 'write'.

This, in our context (question), refers to the time taken to:
*  Read from 'main memory' and write to 'data buffer'.
Or
*  Read from 'data buffer' and write to 'main memory'.


With this, our entire transfer between 'main memory' and 'disk' looks
like following:

Case 1: Read from 'main memory' and write to 'disk'.
*  DMA: read from 'main memory' and write to 'data buffer' in
        cycle stealing mode.
*  Disk: read from 'data buffer' and write to
         'sector' (disk -> surface -> track -> sector).

Case 2: Read from 'disk' and write to 'main memory'.
*  Disk: read from sector' (disk -> surface -> track -> sector) and
         write to 'data buffer'.
*  DMA: read from 'data buffer' and write to 'main memory' in
        cycle stealing mode.


Note:
In both the above cases, DMA blocks CPU's memory-dependent instructions
only, for transfer between 'main memory' and 'data buffer' only.
That is:
*  CPU's non-memory-dependent instructions are not blocked and are
   executed in parallel while DMA is operating.
*  DMA takes control only for transfers between 'main memory'
   and 'data buffer', not for transfers between 'data buffer' and 'disk'.


Coming to the question, it asks "'maximum' percentage of time the CPU
gets blocked during DMA operation".
But, from above information, we came to know CPU is not blocked entirely
during DMA transfer as it can continue non-memory-dependent instruction
operations.

So, to satisfy 'maximum' condition (of the question), DMA must be busy
transferring 4 B words consecutively.
This means, our CPU sends read / write request to DMA continuously
and DMA keeps transferring continuously in cycle stealing mode, meanwhile
CPU goes back to execute another instruction.


Now, with above information, let's answer this from 2 perspectives.



General or basic perspective
============================

In our common calculation, we concluded at the statement:
'4 Byte transfer take 4 memory cycles'.
This '4 B transfer' is transfer from 'data buffer' to 'disk' or vice-versa.

Time taken to transfer data from 'data buffer' to 'disk' or vice-versa = 4 memory cycles.
Time taken to transfer data from 'main memory' to 'data buffer' or vice-versa = 1 memory cycle.
Total time for DMA operation = time('main memory' to 'data buffer') + time('data buffer' to 'disk')
Total time for DMA operation = 1 memory cycle + 4 memory cycles
Total time for DMA operation = 5 memory cycles

Maximum time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = 1 memory cycle.
Percentage of time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = ((1 / 5) * 100) = 20 %

Precisely, it would be:
time('main memory' to 'data buffer') = 40 nano-seconds
time('data buffer' to 'disk') = 153 nano-seconds
Total time for DMA operation = time('main memory' to 'data buffer') + time('data buffer' to 'disk')
Total time for DMA operation = 40 + 153 nano-seconds
Total time for DMA operation = 193 nano-seconds

Maximum time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = 1 memory cycle.
Maximum time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = 40 nano-seconds
Percentage of time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = ((40 / 193) * 100) = 20.72 % = 20 %


Now, if you're talking from GATE exam's perspective, then the
questioner's perspective play a vital role, and given that the options
for the said question were [10, 25, 40, 50], it can be well assumed
that either:
*  Questioner asked for nearest value.
Or
*  (Sorry for saying this, but ...) either question is poorly drafted
   or
   questioner's own knowledge is limited (or it could be us), and hence
   (s)he is assuming that both operations overlap in time,
   that is "'data buffer' to 'disk' transfer" begins immediately
   as "'memory' to 'data buffer' transfer" begins.

If it was the first case, we got our answer, else if it is the second one,
then our answer follows as:

Time taken to transfer data from 'data buffer' to 'disk' or vice-versa = 4 memory cycles.
Time taken to transfer data from 'main memory' to 'data buffer' or vice-versa = 1 memory cycle.
Total time for DMA operation = max(time('main memory' to 'data buffer'), time('data buffer' to 'disk'))
Total time for DMA operation = max(1 memory cycle, 4 memory cycles)
Total time for DMA operation = 4 memory cycles

Maximum time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = 1 memory cycle.
Percentage of time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = ((1 / 4) * 100) = 25 %

Precisely, it would be:
time('main memory' to 'data buffer') = 40 nano-seconds
time('data buffer' to 'disk') = 153 nano-seconds
Total time for DMA operation = max(time('main memory' to 'data buffer'), time('data buffer' to 'disk'))
Total time for DMA operation = max(40 nano-seconds, 153 nano-seconds)
Total time for DMA operation = 153 nano-seconds

Maximum time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = 1 memory cycle.
Maximum time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = 40 nano-seconds
Percentage of time for which CPU gets blocked during DMA operation = ((40 / 153) * 100) = 26.14 % = 26 % ~= 25 %



This should answer the question, as far as GATE exam is concerned.
And if that suffices, then you can safely stop reading here.


Now, from a (more) technical perspective, there's little more than this,
which, as far as I know, have documented in following section.


Little more technical perspective
=================================

DMA can be configured in 3 ways as follows:
*  Single bus detached DMA.
    -----
   | CPU |-----+--------+--------+-----------------+------
    -----      |        |        |                 |
             --+--    --+--    --+--         ------+------
            | DMA |  | I/O |  | I/O |  ...  | Main Memory |
             -----    -----    -----         -------------

*  Single bus integrated DMA.
    -----
   | CPU |-----+--------+-----------------+------
    -----      |        |                 |
             --+--    --+--         ------+------
            | DMA |  | DMA |  ...  | Main Memory |
             -----    --+--         -------------
            | I/O |     |\      -----
             -----      | -----| I/O |
                        +----   -----
                       | I/O |
                        -----

*  I/O bus.
    -----
   | CPU |-----+-----------------+------
    -----      |                 |
             --+--         ------+------
            | DMA |  ...  | Main Memory |
             --+--         -------------
               |
           ----+--------+--------------- I/O bus
               |        |
             --+--    --+--
            | I/O |  | I/O |  ...
             -----    -----


In 'single bus detached DMA', a single DMA operation takes 2 memory
cycles per transfer, where as others take just 1 memory cycle per
transfer, which has an impact on our answer.
Among these, we have assumed that 'single bus detached DMA' is 'NOT' used.


The 'data buffer' which we have mentioned in previous sections, any one
among following:
*  Data buffer register in DMA controller only.
*  I/O buffer in disk controller only.
*  Data buffer in 'DMA controller' as well as I/O buffer in
   'disk controller' both.

Among these, we have assumed the second one, that is, I/O buffer in
disk controller as 'data buffer'.
Any other configuration will change the answer.


We neglected rotational delay, which could have been calculated from
the given information, further increasing the transfer time.

Apart from all theses, we have neglected all other delays and a lot
more information which were not given, which could have drastic impact
on our answer.
```

This completes my answer for corrected question.

But, if in-case there were no typo errors and the '1 byte word' phrase was intentional, then though the initial calculations would look same, the final answer would differ.

First of all, the question would contradict its size of 1 word as for read, it will be 1 B whereas for write, it will be 4 B, leading to 2 different results, one for read and one for write. And if you decide to take average, you would get somewhere near 50 to 60 %.

Solving the second case would make this answer too lengthy, so, not attempting.

I hope this clarifies some of your doubts or might help someone else (if my answer's contents are not wrong), even though you accepted an answer long before this reply.

Also, here's some references which you might want to look at:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/272470/how-does-a-dma-controller-work
- [Direct memory access DMA - how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150719/direct-memory-access-dma-how-does-it-work)
- [On DMA and CPU Concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913855/on-dma-and-cpu-concurrency)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/direct-memory-access-dma-controller-in-computer-architecture/

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake is its not

> no. of tracks read
>
> Its actually no. of interrupts occured (no. of times DMA came up with its data, these many times CPU will be blocked)

But again I don't know why 50 has been multiplied,probably because of 1 second, but I wish to solve this without multiplying by 50

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:-

Here, in 1 rotation interface can read 512 KB data. 1 rotation time = 0.02 sec. So, one byte data preparation time = 39.1 nsec ----> for 4B it takes 156.4 nsec. Memory Cycle time = 40ns. So, the % of time the CPU get blocked = 40/(40+156.4) = 0.2036 ~= 20 %. But in the answer booklet options are given as A) 10 B)25 C)40 D)50. Tell me if I'm doing wrong ?